# Can dangerouslySetInnerHTML preserve tag name case?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following:

```
this.props.message = '<NavLink to="/mypage">Click Me</NavLink>';
```

Which I want to render, so using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` I try

```
dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.message }}
```

But it renders `<navlink to="/mypage">Click Me</navlink>` (notice tag names all lower case)

Which means the `<NavLink />` component is now not recognised.

Is there a way to preserve the case?

Comment: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, as the name implies, is for rendering HTML, not JSX. The case doesn't matter. The string will never be interpreted as JSX.

Comment: Yeah, it needs a design rethink - thanks

Comment: Also this cannot work because JSX is usually transformed to "normal" JavaScript at build time, i.e. the browser never sees or can do anything with JSX. But the value of the string would only be evaluated in the browser.

Comment: Rendering strings in React is not a trivial task and should be avoided when possible. Certainly should be avoided here because you're in control of `this.props.message`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645424/render-html-string-in-isomorphic-react-app for reference.

Answer (score 1):

As @Felix mentioned, `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is for rendering HTML, not JSX.

`this.props.message = <NavLink to="/mypage">Click Me</NavLink>;`

You should be able to just render this as:

`{this.props.message}`

Alternatively, you could use a `render` prop:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const A = ({ render, children }) => {
  return <div style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>{render(children)}</div>;
};

const B = ({ name }) => {
  return <div style={{ color: "red" }}>{name}</div>;
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <A
      render={name => {
        return <B name={name} />;
      }}
    >
      Colin
    </A>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/3r7qxqmy26).

Comment: Not when it's passed as a prop

Comment: You could use a `render` prop here, I think (see addendum).