# How to parse mixed content into React components?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, parsing, react-component

I'm ingesting content from an API which sends through HTML which also has third-party template tags. An example could be:

```html
<h1>Title<h1>
<p>This is some content.</p>
[Tag]Other content[/Tag]
<p>More random content.</p>
```

If it wasn't for the template tags, I could just put everything through `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, however I'd like to be able to separate the content inside of `[Tag]...[/Tag]` (square brackets, not HTML) into its own React component along the lines of `<Tag content={content} />`.

How would I be able to go about parsing out that component whilst then concatenating all the pieces back together?

Thank you!

Comment: Rendering from a string was discussed on SO. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645424/render-html-string-in-isomorphic-react-app for example.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `renderToString` for this case

```
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'
...
const template = `<h1>Title<h1>
<p>This is some content.</p>
[Tag]Other content[/Tag]
<p>More random content.</p>`

const html = template.replace(/\[Tag\].+\[\/Tag\]/, renderToString(<Tag content={content} />))
```

Comment: Available in the browser, giving it a shot. Thank you!