# How to allow HTML templates define React components the same as Vue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, templates, vue.js

In Vue you can have something like.

```
<!-- index.php -->

<div id="app">
    <section>
        <main>
            <h1>Main</h1>
            <some-component></some-component>
        </main>
        <aside>
            <h2>Side</h2>
            <another-component></another-component>
        </aside>
    </section>
</div>

<script>
    Vue.component('some-component', { template: '<div>hello - {{ this.$parent.test }}</div>' });
    Vue.component('another-component', { template: '<div>world - {{ this.$parent.test }}</div>' });

    new Vue({el: '#app', data: () => ({test: 123})});
</script>
```

which will render all the registered components and you'll end up with something like

```
<div id="app">
    <section>
        <main>
            <h1>Main</h1>
            <div>hello - 123</div>
        </main>
        <aside>
            <h2>Side</h2>
            <div>world - 123</div>
        </aside>
    </section>
</div>
```

---

How can the same thing be done using React?

I've tried silly things like

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.kids}</div>
    }
}


if (document.getElementById('app')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<App kids={document.getElementById('app').innerHTML)} />, document.getElementById('app'));
}
```

---

The overall goal is to be able to have normal html templates, then scatter various react components throughout where needed.

Ideally it should be contained with a single renderless-like component which can provide down global data using the context api.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the point in using React if you want vue/angular-like templates, use vue instead. React uses javascript xml or jsx if you will, whichs do look like templates but are actually giving you the benefit of everything javascript can do.

Although, if you want everything in a single component, there's nothing stopping you from doing so.

now if you meant that you want a single component that renders all children, you aren't far off tbh. Here's a simple example from [codeburst](https://codeburst.io/a-quick-intro-to-reacts-props-children-cb3d2fce4891)

```
const Picture = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={props.src}/>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}


render () {
  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <Picture src={picture.src}>
          //what is placed here is passed as props.children  
      </Picture>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: It's not that we want angular/vue templates - it's that we do not want to create an SPA - it needs to be a traditional PHP server side rendered application. which a handful of dynamic components. So making it completely JS wouldn't be appropriate.

However I think you have misunderstood - we do not "want" to have it in a single component, the only reason that was mentioned is that state needs to be able to be shared between them. e.g. errors from validation

Comment: read your other answer, and in that case you can use portals everywhere. which you create with React.portal before the return statement. But tbh, I am pretty sure it isnt meant to be used like that. (But you can). https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Answer (score 0):

React is not template-based but uses JS or JSX to define components, so options are limited.

It's preferable to

It's possible to render HTML snippets with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.props.kids}/>
```

This doesn't allow to use custom components inside snippets because React components don't use selectors. It may be possible to parse a template with HTML parser to a hierarchy of React elements and then replace custom elements like `<some-component>` with corresponding React components, like shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45645424/render-html-string-in-isomorphic-react-app).

It's possible to define and transpile components on the fly but this isn't recommended in production:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone/babel.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
  var Foo = () => 'Foo';
</script>
...
<script type="text/babel">
  ReactDOM.render(<Foo/>, document.getElementById('foo'));
</script>
```

In order to use context API for multiple components, they should be rendered not as root components with `render` but within a common parent, for instance, as portals with `createPortal`:

```
...
<script>
  var portals = {};
</script>
...
<script type="text/babel">
  portals['#foo'] = <Foo/>;
</script>
...
<script type="text/babel">
  // runs on page load
  var CommonContext = ...;
  var Root = () => (
    <CommonContext.Provider value={...}>
      {Object.entries(portals).map(({ selector, child }) => (
        ReactDOM.createPortal(child, document.querySelector(selector))
      )}
    </CommonContext.Provider>      
  );

  ReactDOM.render(<Root/>, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

Comment: I think this is the opposite way round to what I was trying to explain, I don't want to render HTML inside react, I want to use HTML to define which react components to mount

Comment: I understand that, this is what *This doesn't allow to use custom components...* says about. What you're trying to do is orthogonal to how React apps are developed. Vue can work like that, React can't. It's possible to use workarounds but none of them are straightforward. I added an example how it can be done with Babel but I'd advise against doing this in production. Consider developing React components in JS files. If you need many of them then you will end up with many files.